# Google Fit REST API Adding Weight data that is visible from default web dashboard

Tags: java, rest, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I've been able to retrieve data-sets used by the Google Fit web dashboard  via the REST API but any attempts to add new Data Points fails with the below error. I assume this is by design. However, is it possible to create a data-set and have it displayed by the Google Fit default dashboard or must, I create my own web app and just use the google REST API as a means of getting/setting data from my application.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 

Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Application package name (com.google.android.gms) provided by un-trusted source.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Application package name (com.google.android.gms) provided by un-trusted source."
}
```

Comment: You should be able to insert standard data types.  You will need to create your own data source for them though, which means jumping through some hoops.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do that. I was even able to add points to the datasource the issue is the Google Fit dashboard does not reflect the data added to the datasource. I just want to see the data points from my custom datasource on the google fit dashboard.

Comment: Can you show us code/sample requests you used to add the data? @kfowlks

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this problem of data not showing up in the Dashboard?